# How synchronization performed in multiprocessor system between threads, where thread share data but running in different processors

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessor

1.a)How synchronization performed in multiprocessor system between threads, where thread share data but running in different processors. 
1.b)Is single processor thread synchronization system technique like mutex and semaphore will fail if used in multiprocessors environment

Comment: This question is hardware / operating system dependent - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science) for an outline on this complex subject

Comment: @auburg:can you help me to understand how it will done if Operating system is    Linux and ruining on a hardware which have multiprocessor support.

Comment: No ! You need to study the documentation available for Linux and ask pertinent questions on the Linux forums (and here) as to what you don't understand. There's plenty of information available on the subject.

Comment: @auburg:I tried to search specific information synchronization on multiprocessor system but I didn't got any good tutorial. do you have any tutorial link which can help to understand concept in multiprocessor environment.

Comment: What about this https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/master/lectures/smp.html

Comment: @auburg: Thanks :) It was enough to kick start....